# ItemUpdated vs FieldUpdated

Tags: event-receivers, events

I have a user request where a Document Library with Content Approval turned on, wants the name of the person who approved the document.  So I created an "Approver" column and want to create an Event Receiver to capture the users name that is approving the document and write it out to the "Approver" column.  Should I use ItemUpdated or FieldUpdated ?

Bismarck

Answer (score 1):

You want the ItemUpdated event on the SPItemEventReceiver which occur after the ListItem (ie content) has been updated.

The FieldUpdated on the SPListEventReceiver happens after someone made a change to the field like made it required not when the content changes